# Titanium compatibility with Android

Tags: android

Hi i am working on android application development.I am using Titanium studio for development.
I create a simple application & when i run it it show me Android emulator with home screen.It not showing any output regarding my application. I tried my code for iPhone it works fine but not for the android.
Thank u for help..

Comment: please paste your code here, so i can check your exact problem with titanium studio in android...